# iOS Memory Warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, out-of-memory

In Objective-C application, when receiving memory warning, I clear image cache (memory and disk) and remove all data from previous controllers (like cells, images, arrays etc).

When returning back they did load after a while (so clearing data is working and image do reload taking time so the cache is invalidated).

The problem is on monitoring Memory used by App, it doesn't show a significant decrease after handling the memory warning.

I check the memory levels using either Instruments or Debug Navigation on Real device (calling the memory handler custom action on a certain event in all controllers) And using simulator using Simulate Memory Warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I can see that you are monitoring the memory increases / decreases, and you are trying to release as much memory as you can when it increases. That's fine but if there are any [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), then that strategy will not do anything.

I believe that you need to debug your code searching for memory leaks. I recommend you to use the Xcode memory graph debugger, it's a really efficient tool to find memory leaks problems. [Here](https://medium.com/zendesk-engineering/ios-identifying-memory-leaks-using-the-xcode-memory-graph-debugger-e84f097b9d15) is a post that shows you how to use it.

Comment: Thanks alot, the tool was helpful, and detected some memory leaks